# A value of type 'List<Country> can't be returned from function 'fetchCountries' because it has a return type of 'Future<Country>'

Tags: dart

i have a problem with my dart code. I'm trying to fetch some data from an API, it returns a JSON array. I created a model which parses my JSON. After that I try to pass to my function the data I fetched, but this error shows up: "A value of type 'List can't be returned from function 'fetchCountries' because it has a return type of 'Future'".

Does anyone have a clue?

### Country model

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

List<Country> countryFromJson(String str) => List<Country>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Country.fromJson(x)));

class Country {
    String country;
    int cases;
    int todayCases;
    int deaths;
    int todayDeaths;
    int recovered;
    int active;
    int critical;
    int casesPerOneMillion;
    int deathsPerOneMillion;
    int totalTests;
    int testsPerOneMillion;

    Country({
        this.country,
        this.cases,
        this.todayCases,
        this.deaths,
        this.todayDeaths,
        this.recovered,
        this.active,
        this.critical,
        this.casesPerOneMillion,
        this.deathsPerOneMillion,
        this.totalTests,
        this.testsPerOneMillion,
    });

    factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Country(
        country: json["country"],
        cases: json["cases"],
        todayCases: json["todayCases"],
        deaths: json["deaths"],
        todayDeaths: json["todayDeaths"],
        recovered: json["recovered"],
        active: json["active"],
        critical: json["critical"],
        casesPerOneMillion: json["casesPerOneMillion"],
        deathsPerOneMillion: json["deathsPerOneMillion"],
        totalTests: json["totalTests"],
        testsPerOneMillion: json["testsPerOneMillion"],
    );
}
```

### Country service

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/country.dart';

Future<Country> fetchCountries() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries');

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    return countryFromJson(response.body);
  }
  else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Country')
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have the fix in your error message: Remove the `Future`. Return `Country`

Comment: But how will I be able to fetch data from API?

Comment: The return type of `fetchCountries` should be `Future<List<Country>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your function definition, you should have

```
Future<List<Country>> fetchCountries() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries');

  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    return countryFromJson(response.body);
  }
  else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load Country')
  }
}
```

So you should be awaiting a list of country and not a single country. 
Hope it helps!